# Retreive the post data of datepicker in controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

My Codeigniter view:

```
<input id ="start_date" name="start_date" type="text" class="datepicker" />

<script>
    $(function () {

        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
        $(".datepicker").datepicker().each(function (){
            var start_date = $("input[name=start_date]").val();
            var base_url = '<?=base_url()?>';
            $.ajax
            ({
                'type': 'POST',
                'url': base_url + 'app/application/testdata/'+start_date,
                'success': function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

My Codeigniter controller:

```
public function testdata()
{
    $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
}
```

I am trying to get the post data of my datepicker (start-date) in my controller. But the console.log(response) prints "false" instead of the selected date. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make your controller return the result:

```
public function testdata()
{
    $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
    // Return test data here to Ajax.
}
```

Could you please modify your ajax to :

```
            $.ajax
            ({
                'type': 'POST',
                'data':{'start_date':start_date},
                'url': base_url + 'app/application/testdata/'+start_date,
                'success': function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
```